# What is the difference between attr.property and property in angular template?

Tags: angular, attr, angular-template

```
 <input class=" form-control" formControlName="employeeId" [attr.disabled]="loginNameDisable ? null : ''"/>
```

Input works normally

```
<input class=" form-control" formControlName="employeeId" [disabled]="loginNameDisable ? true : false"/>
```

Input not working

**Why is input not working?**

**What is the difference between [attr.property] and property in angular template?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that there is no `Input` property named `disabled` and hence you have to use `[attr.disabled]` to send an expression.

If you would like to use native `disabled`, try using `disabled={{<expression>}}`. This way it will always be disabled, no matter if you send false. Please check the below link for proof.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amtzxw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**However, the recommended way is `[attr.disabled]`.**

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: If Input does not have a diable attribute, why does [attr.disabled] work normally?

Comment: Thats how Angular built it. You can set any attribute using `[attr.<attribute_name>]`.